# php syntax error while am trying to add foreach inside function

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax, foreach

i am trying to use foreach function into other function to write file

this is foreach function

```
foreach ($from as $ex) { 
                echo "$ex->id ;";
                echo "$ex->nickname ;";
                echo "$ex->date ;";
                echo "$ex->content ;";
                echo "\n";
                }
```

and this is codeigniter write file function,i want to add my foreach to the last parameter

```
write_file('reports/report-' . date('h-i-s-d-m-y') . '.csv',$i_want_to_put_my_foreach_here);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a foreach loop as a function parameter like that. You need to separate them. In this case, you probably want to use a temporary variable:

```
foreach ($from as $ex) { 
    $string = "$ex->id ;";
    $string .=  "$ex->nickname ;";
    $string .=  "$ex->date ;";
    $string .=  "$ex->content ;";
    $string .=  "\n";
    write_file('reports/report-' . date('h-i-s-d-m-y') . '.csv', $string);
}
```

Comment: it works,but it adds the first row only of the loop.

Comment: Then either make `write_file()` append to the file, or take that out of the loop and append the entire string at the end.

Comment: @user2976078: Maybe you simply want to write to file after the loop? (If this is maybe part of an outer loop, who knows with what little info you’ve given?) Then you should properly initialize the variable.

Comment: Actually, this looks like you want to write CSV data, so you should look into [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).